# React Conditional routing with Navigate and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help figuring out something.

I have the following React app:

```
function App() {
  const [walletConnected, setWalletConnected] = useState("")

  async function checkConnection() {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' }) 
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      setWalletConnected(true)
    } else {
      setWalletConnected(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/signin' element={<SignInPage/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/generator' element={<GeneratorPage/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/ethers' element={<Ethers/>}/>
        <Route exact path='/connected' element={<GeneratorPage/>}/>
        {checkConnection() && <Route
          exact
          path="/gated"
          element = {walletConnected ? <GeneratorPage/> : <Navigate to="/" />} /> 
        }
      </Routes> 
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

What I am basically trying to implement is conditional routing. But it doesn't work in it's current form.

What's interesting is, if I don't use `<Navigate to= />` but instead render a page element, the code works fine and I get the page to render correctly.

It seems what is happening is that the condition doesn't get switched fast enough, and React instantly navigates to the page, without giving a chance for `<GeneratorPage/>` to render.

Comment: You need `{walletConnected && ...}` (calling a function that changes state inside JSX causes an infinite loop to boot) You should also initialize the state to `false`, not `""`

Comment: `checkConnection()` is async and therefore returns a default Promise, i.e. a truthy value. Still, even if you returned something from the function: a) not how react works b) you'd still be calling an async function inside JSX, which is not how it works

Comment: Thanks! This actually didn't work and just ended up sending me to a blank page with my current code

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the condition like this

```
checkConnection() && <Route ....
```

but your `checkConnection()` method doesn't return anything.

You can call the `checkConnection()` inside an useEffect

```
useEffect( () => {
  checkConnection()
},[])
```

and modify the code like this

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/gated"
    element = {walletConnected ? <GeneratorPage/> : <Navigate to="/" 
/>

.. other routes
```

Comment: Thanks! However, using useEffect fails to set the state to true even though the conditions are met. Even after setting both conditions to {setWalletConnected(true)} which is weird.

Comment: {walletConnected && <Route
          exact
          path="/gated"
          element = {walletConnected ? (<GeneratorPage/>) : (<Navigate to="/" />)} /> 
        } 

with useEffect works, but now it doesn't redirect